# Maximality of measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I read the following comments in a measure theory course :

> When an outer measure $m_∗$ is constructed form a pre-measure $m_0$
> defined on an algebra $A$ then $A \subset \Sigma_∗$ (sigma-algebra) and $m_0 = {m_∗}_{|}{_{Σ∗}}={\mu}_{|}{_{Σ∗}}$.
>
> When $m_∗$ is constructed form a pre-measure $m_0$ defined on an
> algebra $A$ then $µ$ is maximal in the following sense: For any measure $ν$
> on $\Sigma_∗$ such that $m_0 = {ν}_{|}{_{Σ∗}}$ we have $ν(S) ≤ µ(S)$ for any $S \in \Sigma_∗$.

But here don't we have $m_0={\mu}_{|}{_{Σ∗}}={ν}_{|}{_{Σ∗}}$ ? So I do not see how is the result $ν(S) ≤ µ(S)$ $\forall S \in \Sigma_∗$ interesting since we already have an equality. I am asking this because the next sentence is

> In addition, if $\mu(S)< \infty$ then $\nu(S)=\mu(S)$.

Thus, I struggle to see why does not $$m_0={\mu}_{|}{_{Σ∗}}={ν}_{|}{_{Σ∗}}\implies ν(S) = µ(S)\forall S \in \Sigma_∗$$
hold. If I believe the last sentence I should choose a set $S$ with infinite measure to have the strict inequality.

Comment: You don't have that $\mu=\nu$ on $\Sigma_*$, but on $A$. You need the uniqueness of extension to minimal $\sigma$-algebra, which holds when the measure is $\sigma$-additive. It isn't necessarily unique otherwise. Right? Btw, what is the definition of $\mu$? Would you please write down the definitions and statements so that we can know precisely what confuses you, and not just cite them?

Comment: There was a typo in my course, a confusion between $A$ and the sigma algebra